# How to display a list based on group in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Hey everyone so I am new to Sharepoint, it is used by my new company and I am now tasked with managing and maintaining the website. They want to me display different lists depending on what group a user has on the login screen. I am unsure how to do this in sharepoint and their documentation was rather confusing. Any ideas. Something like

```
if(user.groupName === 'IT') {
return <ItList/>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, SharePoint doesn’t directly support filtering list views based on user permissions. You can only assign item-level permissions to each list item based on the user’s location. This way, users will only see items for which they have permissions.

Here's a thread with the same needs as yours for your reference:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-list-view-depending-on-user-group/m-p/2077064

Comment: I have downvoted for the vote begging - this material has been removed from your material before, and is discouraged here. Please let votes happen organically.